# Eclipse auxilery app "aapt.exe" keeps crashing

Tags: android, eclipse

Dose "aapt.exe" write a log file, and if so, how does one view it?

Starting this morning I began getting messages that "aapt.exe has stooped working" "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly...." I turned on "Preferences | Android | Build | Build Output | Verbose" but I don't see any messages in the console, Log Cat or Errors window. This error happens every time a Clean All finishes, and sporadically whenever Eclipse is running (even if it's in the background, sitting idle, with no open code windows.

I found a few entries like this in the Windows Event Viewer. Only the Process ID and Start Time seem to change. The "exception code 0xc0000005" usually indicates an out of bounds memory access (I think.)

**Faulting application aapt.exe, version 0.0.0.0, time stamp 0x52684cb5, faulting module aapt.exe, version 0.0.0.0, time stamp 0x52684cb5, exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset 0x0003cf2a, process id 0x428, application start time 0x01cefa0f2db629c3.**

I think it started when I forgot to put an opening quote on an .xml string, but I fixed that and it kept happening. I then deleted the entire project the error occurred in and I still get the message.

Comments / ideas welcome - Joe

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663749/aapt-exe-has-stopped-working)?

Comment: has there been any windows updates in the night? You may try to rollback them.

Comment: Hi payele:
Looked at your link and had an idea. I exported my entire current workspace (tons of projects) to a backup device, Created a new workspace. Imported into the new workspace the 4 projects I'm currently working on and everything seems to work OK now. I'm guessing that something in my old workspace has some bad codes in it. Someday when time allows I'll make another workspace and re-import all my old projects, one at a time, till I find out which project crashes the system and try to debug that project. It's just annoying that I can't even figure out which project is at fault. Thanks

Comment: I figured out what caused my problems. In one of the .xml files I had typed a line that read - android:icon="@android:drawable/icmenu_add" - but it should have read - android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" - I forgot the "_" char between ic & menu. It's just really annoying that such a minor opps could take 2 days and a few posts to StackOverflow to solve. I know in this business you have to just take this stuff with a grain of salt, but someone should know it's annoying and try to fix it. - Thanks to those who offered help/support - Joe